# Flag first two raw that has a value in a group

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, qsqlquery

First i am not an expert in sql. That's why am seeking for help. 
I have an oracle view which contain employees attendance records including late attendance days.
Columns :

Employee Number ,Date, In-Time, Out-time, Late_Arrival (If late currently getting marked as '1')

I want to mark each employees fist two late arrivals of a month as "G". from a query.

Please help me with this.

```
SELECT l.EMP_NO,l.ACCOUNT_DATE,l.IN_TIME,l.OUT_TIME,l.LATE_COMING_15 as 
late_arrival,
          (case when l.LATE_COMING_15 = 1 and
          row_number() over (partition by trunc(l.ACCOUNT_DATE),l.LATE_COMING_15
order by  l.IN_TIME
                            ) <= 2 
     then 'G'
end) as flag
from LATE_EARLYDEP l

WHERE trunc(l.ACCOUNT_DATE) >= to_date('&DATE_FROM','dd/MM/yy') AND 
trunc(l.ACCOUNT_DATE) <=to_date    ('&DATE_TO','dd/MM/yy')

order by 1,2`
```

But am still not getting the required result. as an example employee number 0005's flaged days should be 02/03/2017 & 06/03/2017 . i have uploaded the result to below google drive link

result  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Xw1eXeLyG7M3dtbmJUek5OdG8

Answer (score 1):

This logic:

```
     row_number() over (partition by trunc(l.ACCOUNT_DATE), l.LATE_COMING_15
                        order by l.IN_TIME)
```

Is enumerating the rows for each *day*, not for each *month*.  If you want the first two per month, then you need to change the `partition by` clause:

```
     row_number() over (partition by l.emp_no, trunc(l.ACCOUNT_DATE, 'MON'), l.LATE_COMING_15
                        order by l.IN_TIME)
```

Comment: Still not flagging the required result. see the below google drive result. thank you so much.     https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Xw1eXeLyG7MkJPd2lTamRVa2M

Comment: @KavinduAnthony . . . I think the issue is just the lack of `emp_no` in the `partition by`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to `Row_number` your record *partitioned* on employy, month and separated for late and OK cases (see `PARTITION BY`)
and order them (as required) on the account date.
Finally mark with `G` those late records that has row number 1 or 2.

```
create table IMLATE as
select 1 emp_no, to_date('01012017','ddmmyyyy') ACCOUNT_DATE, 1 late_arrival from dual union all
select 1 emp_no, to_date('02012017','ddmmyyyy') ACCOUNT_DATE, 0 late_arrival from dual union all
select 1 emp_no, to_date('03012017','ddmmyyyy') ACCOUNT_DATE, 1 late_arrival from dual union all
select 1 emp_no, to_date('04012017','ddmmyyyy') ACCOUNT_DATE, 1 late_arrival from dual union all
select 1 emp_no, to_date('01022017','ddmmyyyy') ACCOUNT_DATE, 1 late_arrival from dual;

with late as (
select EMP_NO, ACCOUNT_DATE, LATE_ARRIVAL,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by EMP_NO, trunc(ACCOUNT_DATE,'MM'), LATE_ARRIVAL order by ACCOUNT_DATE) as rn
from IMLATE)
select EMP_NO, ACCOUNT_DATE, LATE_ARRIVAL,
case when late_arrival = 1 and rn in (1,2) then 'G' end sample_late
from late
 order by emp_no, ACCOUNT_DATE;
```

result

```
    EMP_NO ACCOUNT_DATE        LATE_ARRIVAL SAMPLE_LATE
---------- ------------------- ------------ -----------
         1 01-01-2017 00:00:00            1 G           
         1 02-01-2017 00:00:00            0             
         1 03-01-2017 00:00:00            1 G           
         1 04-01-2017 00:00:00            1             
         1 01-02-2017 00:00:00            1 G
```